# swrevealview controller side bar menu wont dismiss after open another view controller [swift]. How should i close it?

Tags: swift, sidebar, swrevealviewcontroller, dismiss

[image]

swrevealview controller side bar menu wont dismiss after open another view controller [swift]. How should i close it?

Comment: Hi Vicky, you must be more accurate, and first show us what you tried. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is menu close event in that controller.

You can manual close menu before you going to push other view controller in UINavigationcontroller.

You can use below code and do some logic with your app navigation functionality.

// Sets the frontViewController using a default set of chained animations consisting on moving the
// presented frontViewController to the right most possition, replacing it, and moving it back to the left position

```
- (void)pushFrontViewController:(UIViewController *)frontViewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Comment: wait i will give you